# Stop and Start autoplay in swiper container based on the Video play and pause event

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I am trying to put a combination of video and image elements inside the swiper container with auto-play attribute. But I tried to stop the autoplay function in swiper when the video is playing and start the autoplay when the video is paused or ended. As well on moving to next slide the video should be autoplayed from the starting. But currently on implementing the condition I am able to stop the autoplay only for the first time and the autoplay is not controllable from the second cycle. Need help to solve the logic. I have tried an example in the below link
https://codepen.io/thajudeencse/pen/QWQRQEM

```
$(function () {

    var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        // Optional parameters
        direction: 'horizontal',
        loop: true,

        // If we need pagination
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',

        // Navigation arrows
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',

        autoplay: 3000
    });

    var v = document.getElementsByClassName("video")[0];
    v.addEventListener ("play", function () {
      mySwiper.autoplay.stop();
    }, true);
   v.addEventListener("ended", function () {
        mySwiper.startAutoplay();
    }, true);
  
});
```

Comment: _"and start the autoplay when the video is paused or ended"_ - then why aren't you handling `pause` events anywhere ...?

Comment: @CBroe I tried pause event too but it didn't work so I just removed them

Answer (score 0):

is this what you were after:

https://codepen.io/ptahume/pen/NWyQydx

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    spaceBetween: 30,
    centeredSlides: true,
    autoplay: {
      delay: 2500,
      disableOnInteraction: false
    },
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
    }
  });

  //$(".video").each(function () {
  //re add to stop all videos auto playing at start
  // $(".video").trigger("pause");
  // });
  var firstload = true;
  $(".video").on("play", function () {
    if (firstload) {
      swiper.autoplay.start();
      firstload = false;
      return;
    }
    swiper.autoplay.stop();
  });

  $(".video").on("ended", function () {
    swiper.autoplay.start();
  });
});
```

I had to rebuild the thing from scratch so may be a bit different from yours sorry, I used the plug-in from https://swiperjs.com/ which I think was the same as yours, I hope this helps

Comment: Hi @Patrick I enhanced your logic a bit extra with adding some other logics, but I am facing an issue while using rewind function in swiper instead of loop. Can you help me in resolving the issue
https://codepen.io/thajudeencse/pen/QWQRQEM

Comment: sorry for the late reply I was away, sure, when you say an issue with the rewind what do you mean exactly sorry, not sure I fully understand?

Comment: There is an option in swiperjs where we can use rewind instead of loop so that the slide automatically rewinds back to the first slide. When I tried to implement the above logic of playing and pausing the autoplay while video is playing the logic is not working. Kindly check the given codepen link where I have implemented the same

Comment: just to confirm did you want the swiper to play the next video when the first one ends and when the second video ends to rewind the slider back to the start to replay the first video?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same

Comment: done please see above new answer

Comment: Hi @Patrick, I have gone through your solution and found that you have disabled the autoplay, in swiper js and handled the autoplay logic in js by sliding to next slide on completing the video, but in case if there is an combo of images and videos in the slides how will it move to next slide for images if the autoplay is made as false?

Comment: updated and added another answer for you

Comment: couldn't find the new answer

Comment: you can't thee the 3rd new answer above?? the one with this codepen https://codepen.io/ptahume/pen/XWEZBwL ?

Comment: Sorry for bothering you a lot. But still the scroll is not happening as expected. The swiper is going in random speed without waiting for the video to complete and it is not waiting for the mentioned time period for the non video slides

Comment: thats ok, sorry if its not behaving correctly, is the codepen example https://codepen.io/ptahume/pen/XWEZBwL work correctly for you, i checked it in chrome firefox and edge and seams to work alright for me at least, can you confirm if it works for you too please ?

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. I have misplaced the logic, that is why I had an issue. Currently I have to implement the same logic in html5 video tag as given in the below codepen example. The logic here is if the video is paused it should move to next slide, once the cycle is completed and again if the same slide comes we should check the state of the video whether it has been paused or ended. If it is ended we should not play the video, but if the state of the video is ended then we should play the video from the beginning
https://codepen.io/thajudeencse/pen/QWQRQEM

Comment: just to clarify as there was a contradiction when yo say " If it is ended we SHOULD NOT play the video"  you then say "but if the state of the video is ended then we SHOULD play the video" which is it sorry as both statements contradict each other ?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, I meant to say that if the video is paused it shouldn't play and only if the video is ended then it should play from the beginning

Comment: is this what your after: https://codepen.io/ptahume/pen/xxWQaVd?editors=1111 ?

Comment: I have developed the same functionality in slick carousel as the client decided to switch to the slick carousel. But here I am having an issue like for the first time the video is playing as expected and all logic which are mentioned are working as expected, but for the second cycle the autoplay in not stopping when the video is playing
https://codepen.io/thajudeencse/pen/YzaRVLX

Comment: so something like this : https://codepen.io/ptahume/pen/ExEGgmZ?editors=1111 ?

Comment: From the codepen link given by you, the video is playing correctly on first cycle but on the second loop the first video starts playing but the autoplay is not waiting till the video gets paused or ended, it automatically moves to the next slide

Comment: ok try this version https://codepen.io/ptahume/pen/ExEGgmZ?editors=1111 im not 100% sure what your are after but hopefully I will get it right in the end

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job, It will play the next slide at the end of the current slide video and then loop back to the first slide on the last slide video end event effectively always looping all the slides regardless of how many videos you have.

https://codepen.io/ptahume/pen/wvmporW?editors=1111

```js
const getPlayerInstance = function (tindex) {
  const playerDom = $('video-js')[tindex];
  const id = $(playerDom).attr('id');
  return videojs.getPlayer(id);
};
$(document).ready(function () {
  const swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    autoplay: false,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    centeredSlides: true,
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true,
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },
  });
  for (i = 0; i < $("video-js").length; i++) {
    const tplayer = getPlayerInstance(i);
    if (i > 0) {
      tplayer.currentTime(0);
      tplayer.pause();
    }
    tplayer.on('ended', function () {
      if ((swiper.slides.length - 1) === swiper.activeIndex) {
        swiper.slideTo(0);       
      } else {
        swiper.slideNext();   
      }
    })
  }
  swiper.on('slideChange', function (e) {
    const activePlayer = getPlayerInstance(swiper.activeIndex);
    activePlayer.currentTime(0);
    activePlayer.play();
  })
})
```

```css
.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.swiper-slide {
  overflow: hidden;
}

video-js {
  margin-left: calc((100vw - (100vh * 1.7)) / 2);
  margin-right: calc((100vw - (100vh * 1.7)) / 2);
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  video-js {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper mySwiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <video-js
        id="overlayVideo0"
        class="overlayVideo"
        data-account="1752604059001"
        data-player="default"
        data-embed="default"
        controls=""
        data-video-id="4029697544001"
        data-playlist-id=""
        data-application-id=""
        data-object-fit="cover"
        autoplay
        muted
        playsinline
      >
      </video-js>
      <script src="https://players.brightcove.net/1752604059001/default_default/index.min.js"></script>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <video-js
        id="overlayVideo1"
        class="overlayVideo"
        data-account="6269594386001"
        data-player="oHG2GzKTGk"
        data-embed="default"
        controls=""
        data-video-id="6304418462001"
        data-playlist-id=""
        data-application-id=""
        data-object-fit="cover"
        autoplay
        muted
        playsinline
      >
      </video-js>
      <script src="https://players.brightcove.net/6269594386001/oHG2GzKTGk_default/index.min.js"></script>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could re-add the autoplay but it would be tricky to ensure the auto-play time was sufficient for all the videos in each slide, i.e it could be too short for one video or too long for another. This solution is based on the previous one but with any slide that doesn't have a video it uses a timer to play the next slide, I set the timer to 5 seconds but you can change it as need be, NOTE: StackOverFlow code snippets don't support setinterval so it won't work properly here, please check out the codepen link to see if working properly.

I put an empty div slide in the middle of the 2 video slides just for demonstration purposes but the code should work for however you have your setup in terms of video slides and normal slides

https://codepen.io/ptahume/pen/XWEZBwL

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  let myInterval = 0;
  const swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    autoplay: false,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    centeredSlides: true,
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
    }
  });
  const getPlayerInstance = function (tindex) {
    const playerDom = $("video-js")[tindex];
    const id = $(playerDom).attr("id");
    return videojs.getPlayer(id);
  };
  function SlideIt() {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    if (swiper.slides.length - 1 === swiper.activeIndex) {
      swiper.slideTo(0);
    } else {
      swiper.slideNext();
    }
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < $("video-js").length; i++) {
    const tplayer = getPlayerInstance(i);
    if (i > 0) {
      tplayer.currentTime(0);
      tplayer.pause();
    }
    tplayer.on("ended", function () {
      SlideIt();
    });
  }
  swiper.on("slideChange", function (e) {
    const slide = swiper.slides[swiper.activeIndex];
    if ($(slide).find(".overlayVideo").length > 0) {
      const activePlayer = videojs($(slide).find(".overlayVideo").attr("id"));
      activePlayer.currentTime(0);
      activePlayer.play();
    } else {
      myInterval = setInterval(SlideIt, 5000);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.swiper-slide {
  overflow: hidden;
}

video-js {
  margin-left: calc((100vw - (100vh * 1.7)) / 2);
  margin-right: calc((100vw - (100vh * 1.7)) / 2);
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  video-js {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper mySwiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <video-js id="overlayVideo0" class="overlayVideo" data-account="1752604059001" data-player="default" data-embed="default" controls="" data-video-id="4029697544001" data-playlist-id="" data-application-id="" data-object-fit="cover" autoplay muted playsinline>
      </video-js>
      <script src="https://players.brightcove.net/1752604059001/default_default/index.min.js"></script>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <video-js id="overlayVideo1" class="overlayVideo" data-account="6269594386001" data-player="oHG2GzKTGk" data-embed="default" controls="" data-video-id="6304418462001" data-playlist-id="" data-application-id="" data-object-fit="cover" autoplay muted playsinline>
      </video-js>
      <script src="https://players.brightcove.net/6269594386001/oHG2GzKTGk_default/index.min.js"></script>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps